# Mouse hover on element

Tags: selenium, mouseover, selenium-webdriver

http://www.franchising.com/  ---> Mouse over on (Franchises A-Z) ---> need to click Q

I have tried with the following

```
WebElement we1=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='/franchises/']"));

WebElement we2=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='/franchises/q.html']"));

String js = "arguments[0].style.height='auto'; arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';";

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(js, we2); // I have used the script since the we2 is not visible

Actions builder=new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(we1).perform();
Thread.sleep(5000);
we2.click();
```

could any one try and share me the code... Still I'm getting "ElementNotVisibleException"

Answer (score 0):

With firefoxdriver, a lot would depend on what version of driver you are using and what version of Firefox you have on your system since native support would differ based on that.

Following works on Chrome :

```
WebElement link1 = driver.findElementByLinkText("Franchises A-Z");
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(link1).click(driver.findElementByXPath("//a[contains(@href,'franchises/b')]")).perform();
```

Comment: I have tried the above code... Still I'm getting the "Element is not visible" error... So what I have tried in addition to the above code I placed the following script first then the code

String js = "arguments[0].style.height='auto'; arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';";
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(js, driver.findElementByXPath("//a[contains(@href,'franchises/b')]"));

Once i executed the B link becomes like <a href="/franchises/b.html" style="height: auto; visibility: visible;">B</a>

But still I'm getting the "ElementNotVisibleException" error

FF 11, selenium-2.28.0

Answer (score 0):

Before going in to the code i just want to you to ensure the version of Selenium server you are using. Please make it to the updated version of `2.28.x`

**Code:**

```
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.franchising.com/franchises/");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/a"));
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
```

it works fine for me. Try this code. I hope this will work.